# What slows down indexes on a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-update, sql-insert, sql-delete

So I have reviewed the literature on indexes in MySQL, but I am still confused by the following. It was explained that it is possible for an index to slow a MySQL query down in terms of computational time.  It was explained that this is based on the queries that are operated on the table with said index,  called say `index_A`. I understand that at some point MySQL must rewrite its index file for `INDEX_A` as a result of UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE queries that occur on the relevant tables. What I do not understand is how exactly this happens. Must it happen after every UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE? (This does not seem to be the case.) Or does it require a certain number of said operations to be executed before a rewrite is issued? (In which case how would I find out how many?) Or does this depend on the engine that is being used for that table as well? Basically, I want a better understanding of what could cause my indexes to slow queries down so that I can better avoid that in production. Please let me know if anything I have asked is unclear and thank you for your time.

Edit: It seems that the answer lies in a better understanding of Rtrees and Btrees. These are the structures used to manage indexes in various engines in MySQL. I will further review these and hopefully post a definite answer regarding my findings soon.

Comment: Yes, an index must be updated after an update, insert or delete. Otherwise the index isn't very effective. You need to look at your `EXPLAIN` to see where the issue is coming from.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk So its the case that a rewrite is required after a single instance of any of those operations?

Comment: Think of it as the index in the back of some overpriced college textbook. If you insert, update or delete any part of the book, the page numbers have to cascade don't they? Otherwise how will the index locate the record? If this didn't happen, you wouldn't have a very useful index.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk I understand that a tree of sorts is used to manage indexes. Either an R tree or a B tree. It seems possible to allow the tree to become somewhat unbalanced before a rewrite occurs. In that case a threshold of alteration queries would be possible before a rewrite occurred. Based on what you're telling me, that is not the case and a complete rewrite must happen after any alteration. It that correct? It this regardless of engine?

Comment: You haven't mentioned why you should be concerned about the (in the vast majority of cases) the tiny overhead maintaining indexes during updates. RDBMS such as oracle and mysql are designed to make index updates very quick and the overhead is insignificant operationally.

Comment: I haven't heard of the possibility of the tree becoming unbalanced. They may get corrupted. There are mechanisms in place that handle that (indexes get locked). It also depends on the engine (InnoDB, MyISAM). There's also special circumstances that allow you to disable keys (`DISABLE KEYS`).

Comment: @suspectus I have heard from engineers I trust that the overhead is an issue in some cases. That's why I'm asking. Do you have white papers on the subject I could read? I'm interested.

Comment: @AarolamaBluenk what series of operations would corrupt the tree?

Comment: @John Galt It's an issue in exceptional cases. Often these cases are the result of poor table design. The more indexes a table has, and the type of index (data representation, size of index, number of elements) are factors with regard to the overhead incurred during an update.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will do after each query. So for MyIsam bulk insert, we can disable the keys and do all inserts followed by enabling the key back. Please read to know more on [that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html). (This is not available in innodb anyways)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will review this.

Answer (score 1):

I sense that you are confused over what it means to "update the index".  Let me elaborate by saying you have a big table and give you some simplified metrics:

- If you `INSERT` (or update or ...) a million rows into a table, that takes a million units of effort.
- When you `INSERT` one more row, that takes only 1 unit of effort.

To "rebuild the index" takes another million units of work, but this happens only if you explicitly `DROP` and `reCREATE` the index, some cases of `ALTER TABLE`, and a few other obscure actions.

Comment: Thank you. This is actually what I wanted to know. In all this time, I have not  gotten an answer for this. I'd love to read more about this. Do you know a good source for this kind of stuff? A solid book maybe?

Comment: The "High Performance MySQL" is a solid book but perhaps more advanced and more varied.  The online manual (dev.mysql.com) says virtually everything, but it is organized as a reference manual.  I like to recommend my blogs.  Start with [Index Cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql), then move on to some of the links at the end.

Comment: So, I was right in homing in on what "update the index" means?  It is a not-so-common misconception that the _entire_ index is rebuilt.  But once you understand that it is _incrementally_ maintained, you never look back.

Comment: Yup. Understanding the incremental maintenance is a game-changer for me. Thanks.